# [PYTHON]Email and file connection error

Tags: python, file, email, smtp

I tried to find some topic related, found some, tried some suggested solution, but seems not to work.
I'm trying to figure out where I did it wrong, I'm basically listing a directory and putting the output into a text file that I want to send via smtp to dest address.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os, sys
import smtplib

from email.mime.text import MIMEText


# GRABE LISTED DIRECTORY AND CREATE THE FILE #

#open folder and list it
Winpath = "C:\"
dirs = os.listdir(Winpath)

#Put it into file
fo = open("activitygraber.txt", "w+")
for file in dirs:
  fo.write(file + "\n")


# EMAIL IT TO GIVEN ADDRESS #

msg = MIMEText(fo.read())
fo.close()

msg["Subject"] = "Test ActivityGrab"
msg["From"] = "test@test.me"
msg["To"] = "dest@dest.com"

s = smtplib.SMTP("localhost")
s.sendmail("test@test.me", "dest@dest.com", msg.as_string())
s.quit()
```

That's simple code mostly from Python documentation (I'm in the learning curve).
The file is being created and ready to send I guess, but somehow the connection is not being created. I guess it's because my smtp port in not open ? should I tried to connect to a mail service ? then send it from there ?

Here the message I get when I try to send it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\PC\Desktop\testfile.py", line 33, in <module>
s = smtplib.SMTP("localhost")
File "C:\Python27\lib\smtplib.py", line 250, in __init__
(code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
File "C:\Python27\lib\smtplib.py", line 310, in connect
self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
File "C:\Python27\lib\smtplib.py", line 285, in _get_socket
return socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout)
File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 571, in create_connection
raise err
socket.error: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target      machine actively refused it
```

Any help of hint would really be appreciated thanks !
Meanwhile I'm gonna continue to search the cause.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

`s = smtplib.SMTP("localhost")` isn't going to work unless you have a running  SMTP server on your local machine (which you probably don't...).

If you do, make sure it's listening on port 25.

If you don't, you will have to use a remote SMTP server. You can use google's if you have a gmail account, or find a free one that is set up as a mail relay (that means you can use it anonymously), but these are very rare these days.

Comment: Thank you, it make sense I will look into it asap !